# Struts 2 - Dynamically set the method name, from one Action to call another action method, to execute

Tags: java, servlets, struts2

I have one query regarding Struts 2 method invocation. 
Suppose i  want to call method dynamically and that method name will come from DB. so the scenario is, 
there is one Master module and 2 sub modules lets say M1 and M2, Now every request from any module will go through Master Module, so if module M1 ask for method name suppose getName() which exist in M2 action class only, (here M1 is not aware about it), then first M1 will send a request to Master Module (with method name as a parameter) then master module will find out for which method this request is for and then he will call  M2 getName() method. To do this we dont need to Map method getName() into Struts.xml, We have to set this in Action class of Master Module. I am not able to understand how to do this Cause every time Master Module will get some method name (as Parameter) and will call respective action which include that method name.
Please Help

Thanks 
Tapan

Comment: it seems that you don't want struts2 request handling mechanism and what if there exists same method name with multiple modules?

Comment: Hi Umesh thanks for your reply, we have added all the method name in DB against their module name, if method names are duplicate then we will use first method, at index(0), found in our list.

Comment: One more thing i want to ask Generally we decide in JSP which method we r going to call in our action like action="customerAction!getCustomerName.do",so here we know which method we r calling (like getCustomerName method in above), can we make it dynamically? i mean inside action class, can we define the method name (we want to call) of specific action.

Comment: I am not able to get your question properly.but you can define as many number of methods inside your action class and can configure them in your struts.xml.Alternate is let one action handle the all request and fetch method name from the request and than in main method delegate callas to respected methods

Answer (score 0):

IMO:
  you can dynamically pass the method name using below technique

if action="customerActiongetCustomerName.do

```
<action name="customerAction*"
            class="xxxx" method="{1}">
            <result name="success">/yyyy.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: I believe OP has already mentioned that he don't want to set them in struts.xml file

Comment: @ Arun , Thanks Arun,for your answere, but the way you told me, i dont want to use that.